# Emulate real device screen dimensions with iOS emulator

Tags: ios, iphone, ios-simulator

Is it possible with iOS emulator shipped with Xcode and iOS SDK to emulate on the computer the real dimensions of the device on screen independently of the current computer's DPI. What I wanna to achieve is to test on the screen of my computer if the buttons are big enough for the user's fingers !

Comment: Not really, you can use Command + 1/2/3 to change the size of the emulator, I find 2 is reasonably close, a little smaller, but somehow gives a better idea than a little bigger (1)

Comment: No, but I'm not sure this would be a good test anyway. iOS does some pretty fantastic cheats at times; things that look too small to tap are made tappable. Not to say you should get that small, but nothing beats a real device for testing this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

iOS simulator has only 3 possible scales in `Window > Scale` - 100%, 75% and 50%. It doesn't go farther than that. But from what I see non-retina 75% isn't much bigger than iPad screen in reality. Retina is twice that big so it doesn't match. I don't have iPhone to check.